# Get completed survey responses in Survey Monkey

Tags: java, survey, surveymonkey

Is it possible to get completed survey responses from the survey monkey ?
Currently in API documentation I see only

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/{survey_id}/responses -d
```

and I can add also pagination. 
When I am receiving responses each has **"response_status": "xxxx"** , so want to know is there some action like : **get completed survey responses** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/{survey_id}/responses?status=completed
```